# RCTView generated view config for validAttributes does not match native, missing: accessibilityValue

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

Estoy desarrollando mi primera app en react native - expo y al ejecutar "**npm start**" me muestra el siguiente error "**RCTView generated view config for validAttributes does not match native, missing: accessibilityValue**"

La app corre sin problema pero al iniciar me aparece ese error, no tengo idea el porque, adjunto un screenshot.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ese es el error que me da en la consola, pero ese mismo me lo muestra en mi celular iphone 7, probé en un emulador y sucede los mismo.

Agradezco sus colaboraciones.

Answer (score 0):

Yo antes usaba o bien:
npm run android
o bien:
npm run ios

Ahora uso:
expo start

Parece que estás usando ios, intenta con npm run ios

Saludos

Comment: Al ejecutar **npm run ios** me genera el siguiente error: spawn osascript ENOENT

Comment: Hmmm supongo que lo estarás haciendo en un MAC. ¿lo has probado con: expo start?